# Cannot see About page route but able to reach Home page route due to missing <script>

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, redux, react-router, react-router-v4

I cant seem to figure out why I can't access my about page. I can go to my `HomePage` but not my `AboutPage`. When I look into the developer tools, in `localhost:3000` I see the home content with `<script type="text/javascript" src="/bundle.js"></script>`. However, in `localhost:3000/about` I do not see `<script>` ! It is missing the bundle

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Header from './common/Header';
import Footer from './common/Footer';
import {Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import HomePage from './home/HomePage';
import AboutPage from './about/AboutPage';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    this.state = {};
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Header/>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage}/>
          <Route path="/about" component={AboutPage}/>
        </Switch>
        <Footer/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

AboutPage.js

```
import React from 'react';

class AboutPage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    this.state = {};
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        about pagesdfsdf
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default AboutPage;
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import {BrowserRouter} from 'react-router-dom';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import configureStore from './store/configureStore';
import App from './components/App';

const store = configureStore();

render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App/>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Comment: You'll need to add React Router Redux :-) How are you moving between your routes? What is your environment like?

Comment: @Win Was just looking into that. react-router-dom (v4) + redux. Webpack as build tool. Using Express only to serve frontend code. Django as API

Answer (score 1):

`<BrowserRouter>` requires more setup - do you have a server? You'll probably want to switch over to `<HashRouter>` as it's easier to get up and running with. At the very least, it'll fix the problem you have right now and make your code work.

Reference here for the differences: https://medium.com/@pshrmn/a-simple-react-router-v4-tutorial-7f23ff27adf

Comment: Do you think I need `react-router-redux` like suggested? I am dealing with redux

Comment: nah - you should be fine without it.

Answer (score 1):

I will assume you are using webpack for your app.
So in order to make BrowserRouter works you have to provide the following config in your webpack.config.js

In the output section

```
output: {
    filename: 'app.bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    publicPath : '/' // set the public path to root
  }
```

In the server section

```
devServer: {
    hot : true,
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
    historyApiFallback : true,  // set the historyApiFallback to true                  
    compress: true,
    port: 8080
  }
```